# Compare hashed passwords from different webservers

Tags: asp.net, hash, passwords

If I hash a password in asp.net on one webserver. And then set up a login auth webserver server, that uses the same database as the webserver where we hashed the password the first time.. Can I compare hash from the 2'nd webserver.. Or is the first hashed password dependent on a machine key on the first webserver, so it's impossible to login from the 2'nd webserver by comparing the hashes done on 2 different webservers?

Comment: This is implementation-dependent. Some authentication systems add a per-server local component; others do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good hashing functions do not depend on the machine where is hashed, so given the same password/salt, the output is the same.

I recommend you a classical key derivation function such as bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2